# Is there any actual "real" example of a group $G$ having a cardinality of $2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Sorry if this comes across as a silly question, but I will provide some motivation for it. In thinking about the smallest cardinality for a non-trivial group, I first considered the number $3$.

This made sense to me because the basic "rules" for groups sprang to mind: contain the identity and contain an inverse for all elements. Therefore, I figured that **if** $G = \{e,s,s^{-1}\}$ (for some arbitrary composition rule " $\circ\ $") satisfies closure as well, we have a group of order $3$.

However, I quickly thought about $ord(G)=2$ and what that would mean.

if $G=\{e,s\}$, then I suppose $s$ must be its own inverse? In order for this to be a group, closure must also be satisfied.

There are 4 possible permutations (2 of which I believe are guaranteed):

1. $e\  \circ \ e = e$
2. $s\  \circ \ s = e    $  (which is in line with the idea that $s$ must be its own inverse)

However, I don't think there is anyway of knowing ahead of time the following permutations:

3. $e\  \circ \ s = \ ? $ ... to satisfy closure, this is either $s$ or $e$
4. $s\  \circ \ e = \ ? $ ... to satisfy closure, this is either $s$  or $e$

Assuming these are all correct, are there any actual "real" examples using integers, etc that satisfy these properties?

Comment: Of course.  There's $\mathbb{Z}_2$, a myriad of groups of matrices of order 2, the set $\{\pm 1\}$ in the multiplicative group of nonzero reals, etc.

Comment: The integers modulo 2 form a group of order 2 under addition.

Comment: Consider $$\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$$

Comment: @Randall will all groups of order 2 be abelian?

Comment: All groups of order $p$ for any prime $p$ (including $2$) are cyclic, hence abelian.

Comment: @S.Cramer Yes all groups of order $2$ are abelian. You can show that all groups of order $3,4,5$ are also abelian.

Comment: Your hand is more or less forced. Since $e$ is the identity, anything it multiplies with remains fixed. So three of the four entries of the multiplication table are filled in. Then fill in $ss = e$ to get a multiplicative inverse for $s$, as you have done.

Comment: Of course it will be abelian. Any element must commute with itself and with the identity, in any group. In a group of order $2$ that's all you actually have. By the way, there is only one group of order $2$ up to isomorphism, i.e up to changing the names of the elements and the name of the operation. Check it, there is only one way to build a multiplication table.

Comment: The set $\{1,-1\}$ under multiplication, as given by others, is a "real" example, and is the group of units of the integers under multiplication. Groups of units are very important in later work. Then there is the symmetric group on two objects. All groups of order $2$ are isomorphic, but they are not trivial.

Comment: @marcelgoh I am actually a little confused by your example. For example, isn't $1 mod 2 + 1 mod 2$ equal to $2$? Seeing as the set of $n mod 2$ is comprised of $\{0,1\}$, wouldn't that fail under the closure rule?

Comment: @S.Cramer No because addition modulo $n$ is defined by $a+_n b=(a+b)\text{ mod }n$

Comment: @S.Cramer: Mod 2, we have that 2 is equivalent to 0.

Comment: @PeterForeman Then, for clarification, to be technically correct,  should the statement have read "under addition modulo n"? (Haha, not trying to be sassy...just trying to genuinely understand). It seems like you all implicitly understood "under addition" to MEAN "under addition modulo n"...but you can certainly have a composition of purely "Addition" and NOT "Addition modulo n", right?

Comment: @S.Cramer this stuff is so common to experienced mathematicians that no one says "addition modulo $n$" because we all know what is meant.  (It couldn't mean something else and still make sense, as you already pointed out.)

Comment: @S.Cramer You first pick a set and then define a binary operation on it. Only then you can conclude anything about this pair: calculate inverses and other things. Whether you call the operation "addition" or "addition modulo" or "multiplication" or "banana pie" it doesn't matter. Only properties matter. The term "addition modulo" comes from the fact that certain groups arise as quotients of other groups. But that isn't really relevant for now. What is relevant is that $\{0,1\}$ with binary operation given by $x\circ y:=x+y\text{ mod }2$ is a group.

Comment: S. Cramer: "Then, for clarification, to be technically correct, should the statement have read "under addition modulo n"?"  Randall: "this stuff is so common to experienced mathematicians that no one says "addition modulo n" because we all know what is meant."  ... In other words.  Yes.  S. Cramer was utterly correct.  marcelgoh did indeed mean addition modulo $n$ and assumed the implication was clear.  However the term "addition" is actually contextual, and referring to "addition on the reals"  as "addition" no no more correct or wrong then referring to "addition modulo 2" as "addition".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that, in a group with cardinality $2$, the non-identity element is its own inverse.

Furthermore, if $e$ is the identity element, then we must have $e\  \circ \ s = \ s\ \circ \ e = s. $

Thus, the group table is

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\circ & e & s \\
\hline
e & e & s  \\
s & s & e  
\end{array}
$$

This is isomorphic to the group of integers modulo $2$ under addition, which is

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
+ & 0 & 1 \\
\hline
0 & 0 & 1  \\
1 & 1 & 0  
\end{array}
$$

and the group of units in $\mathbb Z$ under multiplication, which is

$$
\begin{array}{c|lcr}
\times & 1 & -1 \\
\hline
1 & 1 & -1  \\
-1 & -1 & 1  
\end{array}
.$$

Answer (score 2):

Other than what symbols we give to the elements, and what symbol we use for the operation, there is exactly *one* group with order $2$.

If the group consists of $\{e,a\}$ and operator $*$ where $e$ is the identity we must have $e*a=a*e = a; e*e=e; a*a = e$.  That's easy to verify.

$e*a=a*e=a;e*e=e$ must follow by definition of identity; and $a$ must have an inverse and it can't be $e$ so the only option is $a$. So this must and does satisfy all axioms except associativity and is the only option that would.  Associativity is ... well obvious consider $x*(y*z)$ if $z = e$ then $x*(y*z)= x*y = (x*y)*e = (x*y)*z$.  If $y=e$ then $x*(y*z) = x*z = (x*y)*z$.  And if $x = e$ then $x*(y*z) = y*z = (x*y)*z$.  And if  $x,y,z \ne e$ then $x=y=z=a$ and $x*(y*z) = a*(a*a) =a*e =a = e*a = (a*a)*a = (x*y)*z$.

Now there are logical ways to consider this group.

$\mathbb Z_2, +$ where $1 + 1 =0$ and $1+0=0+1 = 1$ and $0+0 = 0$, is the most common way.

Another is $\{-1, 1\},\times$ where ... well, the exact multiplication as usual.

Or it could be $\{poptarts, elephants\}, ?$ where $poptarts?elephants = elephants?poptarts = elephants$ and $poptarts = poptarts?poptarts=elephants?elephants$.

This groups are considered to be equivalent and for all purposes "the same".

.......

We often say they are "equivalent up to isomorphism" is that:

That there is  function $f: \mathbb Z_2 \to \{poptarts, elephants\}$ that is one-to-one and onto and such that for any $x,y\in \mathbb Z_2$ we will have that $f(x+y) = f(x)?f(y)$.  This function is called an isomorphism.

We have such an isomorphism in $f(0)=poptarts$ and $f(1) = elephants$.

As $a+b = c$ if and only  ief $f(a)?f(b) =f(c)$.... these two groups behave exactly the same.  They are, in all ways we care about, the same.

So allthough there are many ways to interpret such groups.

(Note with matrix muliplication $\left\{\begin{pmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}$ is *yet* ANOTHER group with $2$ elements.)

But if we assign the identity to $e$ and then other element to $a$ the are all THE SAME.

Comment: I often see the more experienced mathematicians use expressions that I am unfamiliar with. One such expression is "up to isomorphism"...what exactly does that phrase mean? I know what an isomorphism is...but I'm not sure how to interpret that phrase.

Comment: "Up to isomorphism there is exactly one group of order two" means that for any two groups with order $2$, there will be an isomorphism between them.  The phrase is used to suggest that the differences are not interesting.  You can get from one to the other by just renaming the elements and maybe the operation as well.  The same applies for groups of order $3$, there is also one up to isomorphism but it changes at order $4$ where there are two up to isomorphism.

Comment: Well, technically it means $f:G_1\to G_2$ where $f$ is 1-1 and onto and the identity of $e\in G_1$ is mapped to the identity of $e'\in G_2$ and if $a*b = c\in G_1$ then $f(a)\cdot f(b) = f(c)\in G_2$.  .... But what I mean is that the groups act exactly the same.  The only difference is what we label the things.

Comment: That's why I did the stupid poptarts and elephants example.  What matters isn't what we call them but how they behave.  Finite groups, and even infinite groups, will only have so many significantly different structures as there are only so many ways to combine things.  Just like adding oranges is the same as adding apples.  Mod addition with 2 is the same as toggling light switches is the same as multiplying positive and negatives numbers and checking if the numbers are postive and negative.

Comment: Less trivial.  If we consider $\{1,2,3,4\} \times_5$ as a group where $a \times_5 b = a\cdot b \mod 5$i.e. the remainder of $a\cdot b$. (So $3\times_5 4 = 2$ because $3\cdot 4=12$ and $12 = 2+$ some multiple of $5$).  This is a group. (Draw the tables yourself.)  And $\{0,1,2,3\}+_{4}4$ where $a+_4b = a+b\pmod 4$ is also a group.  If we map $0\mapsto 1;1\mapsto 2; 2\mapsto 4; 3\mapsto 3$ we end up with two groups with the exact same structure!

Comment: Is another of framing this (for a mathematical novice/neophyte), "All groups of order two are 'isometrically equivalent' ". I suppose this phrase developed as a way to circumvent the language of saying "these two things are EQUAL"? i.e. we want to specify "in what way" they are equal. They are "equal" in the context of isomorphisms...or, as you all phrase it, "up to isomorphisms". Is that about right?

Comment: That's a pretty good way of putting it!  Obviously they aren't *equal* because they are different things.  But the behave exactly the same so that the are essentially the same in every way we care.  They are "equivalent".  Mathematically we have a concept of equivalence based reflexivity, symmetry, transitivity.  But all this means is... if you replaced one with the other everything would act the same.

Comment: A good example is if $Z_n, +$ means $\{0,1,2,,.....,n-1\}$ and $a+b = c$ means that if $a+b = c \pm $ some multiple of $n$.  And if we define $A\times B$ and $(a,b) + (c,d)  (a+c,b+d)$ then $Z_6$ and $Z_2\times Z_3$ if we let $(0,0)\mapsto 0; (0,1)\mapsto 1;(0,2)\mapsto 2;(1,0)\mapsto 3; (1,1)\mapsto 4; (1,2)\mapsto 5$.  These are essentially the same.  You might wonder why we'd do this but $Z_2\times Z_3$ describes the behaviour better.  It's obvious $2\times(1,0) = (0,0)$ and $3\times(0,1)=(0,0)$ but that means $2\times 3=3+3=0$ and $3\times 2=2+2+2=0$ which is not so obvious.